# Converting two adjacent tables in one sheet to one table using power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet which contains two adjacent tables in which the rows do not relate to each other. I.e.

[image]

I need to convert this to a single table of the form below using power query:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the first table in Power BI, right click it and use [Duplicate or Reference](https://radacad.com/reference-vs-duplicate-in-power-bi-power-query-back-to-basics) to make a copy. In this copy, remove columns 1 to 3, and rename columns 4 and 5 to be named the same way as columns 1 and 2 from the source table. Then use [Append queries as new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries) to combine both tables into one. There you can delete columns 3 to 5 to get the desired result:

[image]